# Parsing JSON from URL and place values in Kendo React DropdownList

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I'm new to programming and Kendo.  I wrote some simple code to produce a single dropdownlist using Kendo React where I hard coded the values -

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { DropDownList } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';
    import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';
    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
        services = [ "Oxygen Therapy", "CPAP-DME Reimbursement", "Empty Deck Maker" ];

        render() {
            return (
            <div>
              <h2>Select CDS Service</h2>
                <DropDownList data={this.services} />
            </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default App;
```

--
Now I need to use the "title" value in a JSON file that is passed to me via a URL and I'm not sure where to start. Here's a sample of the JSON -

```
{
   "services": [
        { 
            "id": "empty-deck-create",
            "title": "Empty Deck Maker",
            "description": "Generates an empty card deck",
            "hook": "empty-deck-create"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will require using the [textField property](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxProps/#toc-textfield). This property tells the DropDown which field in the passed object to display.

```
<DropDownList data={this.services} textField={"title"}/>
```